# Local extrema of function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

$$f (y,z) = aye^z + \sin\left(y\right) + y \cos(y)$$
where $a\in\Bbb R$.

Prove that when |a| < $\sqrt {2}$ then the origin is a local extremum. Also show the origin is not a local extremum when |a| >$\sqrt {2}$.

So I did second derivative test and first derivative to make it equal to $0$:

$$-y\sin\left(y\right)+2\cos\left(y\right)+a\mathrm{e}^z=ay\mathrm{e}^z=0,$$

I separate the a and get $\dfrac {-y\sin\left(y\right)+2\cos\left(y\right)} {(y-1)\mathrm{e}^z}=a$ but am stuck here. Any here would be appreciated. Thanks.